# Complex mask for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, mask

I have a dataframe with a time series in one single column. The data looks like this chart

[image: input]

I would like to create a mask that is TRUE each time that the data is equal or lower than -0.20. It should also be TRUE *before* reaching -0.20 while negative. It should also be true *after* reaching -0.20 while negative.
This version of the chart

[image: output]

is my manual attempt to show (in red) the values where the mask would be TRUE. I started creating the mask but I could only make it equal to TRUE while the data is less than -0.20 `mask = (df['data'] < -0.2)`. I couldn't do any better, does anybody know how to achieve my goal?

Comment: What is the logic for the excluded part after 2021?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data?

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: @itprorh66 this is actually one of the rare cases where an image **is appropriate**. This is showing the shape of the data and illustrating relatively well how to select the data. An **additional** sample of the data as text would however be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach could be to group segments that are entirely below zero, and then for each group verify whether or not there any values below `-0.2`.

[image]

See below for a full reproducible example script:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


np.random.seed(167)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"y": np.cumsum([np.random.uniform(-0.01, 0.01) for _ in range(10 ** 5)])}
)
plt.plot(df)

gt_zero = df["y"] < 0
regions = (gt_zero != gt_zero.shift()).cumsum()

# here's your interesting DataFrame with the specified mask
df_interesting = df.groupby(regions).filter(lambda s: s.min() < -0.2)

# plot individual regions
for i, grp in df.groupby(regions):
    if grp["y"].min() < -0.2:
        plt.plot(grp, color="tab:red", linewidth=5, alpha=0.6)

plt.axhline(0, linestyle="--", color="tab:gray")
plt.axhline(-0.2, linestyle="--", color="tab:gray")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

## Idea

Group by consecutive values of same sign, and then check if the minimum of such a group is less than the defined treshold.

## Implementation

First, we want to separate negative from positive values.

`negative_mask = (df['data']<0)`

We then can create classes (ordered with integers) for each consecutive positive or negative series. The class increases by one each time the data changes sign.

`consecutives = negative_mask.diff().ne(0).cumsum()`

We then select only the data where the minimum of the group of consecutive elements is less than 0.2.

`df.groupby(consecutives).filter(lambda df : df[0].min() < -0.2)`

## Example with random data

We can try our example with random data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.randint(-300, 300, size=1000)/1000
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["data"])
```

### Output

```
    data
2   -0.030
3   -0.194
4   -0.229
5   -0.280
6   -0.179
... ...
991 -0.293
995 -0.247
996 -0.062
997 -0.072
999 -0.250

363 rows × 1 columns
```